# Adding in PHP returns string addition. 10+12=1012!!!! I need 10+12=22

Tags: php

My Code :

```
$gettotz=0;
while($mycartqry=mysqli_fetch_array($cartqry)){
                    $one=$mycartqry['nos'];
                    $two=$gettotz;
                echo $gettotz.=$myVar+$myVar2;
            }
```

There are two values in db viz 10 and 12.my answer is coming as 01012. My answer should be 22...Help pls

Comment: `.=` means handle it as strings. `=` means use appropriate method. Change it to `echo $gettotz=$myVar+$myVar2;`

Comment: Oh! ok.. so what should i do to get the tot after the while loop..!

Comment: Thank @Andreas for replying :)

Comment: Change `$gettotz.=$myVar+$myVar2;` to `$gettotz +=$myVar+$myVar2;`

Comment: That's a syntax warning @Nigel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$gettotz=0;
while ($mycartqry=mysqli_fetch_array($cartqry)){
    $one = $mycartqry['nos'];
    $gettotz += $one;
    // what is `$myVar` and `$myVar2` is unclear
    // but if they exists you can also add'em:
    // $gettotz += $one + $myVar + $myVar2;
}
echo $gettotz;
```

Comment: Superb ! THANKS SOOO  MUCH... iIt worked ! only one change $gettotz += $gettotz+$one; so that in loop it gets added! THANKS SOOO MUCH @u_mulder

Comment: Just for info can i use SUM(nos) in my mysqli query ??

Comment: Yes, you can. And btw with `$gettotz += $gettotz+$one` you will get wrong results, as you increase `$gettotz` with `$gettotz` value every iteration.